Why does passing bearer token to a shell script not work but embedding the value does
I have a shell script foo.sh
curl -i -X GET 'https://example.com/bar' \                                                                                                                      
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer abc123def456'                                                                                                                     

which works fine.
However if I change it to use an argument for the value of bearer token ...
curl -i -X GET 'https://example.com/bar' \                                                                                                                      
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer $1'                                                                                                                               

and invoke it like this ...
$ foo.sh abc123def456   

The curl request returns as unauthorised . I have tried various ways of providing the value to foo.sh. Attempt one ...
$ . ./foo.sh $(python -c "import get_token; print(get_token.get_token())")                                                                                     

... Attempt two ...
$ python -c "import get_token; print(get_token.get_token())" > secret_temp.txt                                                                                 
$ . ./foo.sh $(cat secret_temp.txt)                                                                                                                            

... but the result is the same.

Variables are not expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes.

Separately, after you fix the quotes so $1 is in a double-quoted context, note that your expansions ($(cat ...), $(python ...)) also should be in a double-quoted context. When you use ./yourscript $(foo) you have no control over how many arguments the output of foo gets split and globbed into; to make sure it's exactly one, you need to use ./yourscript "$(foo)" with the quotes. Same applies for variables in general: ./yourscript "$foo" not ./yourscript $foo.
